# django renaming image file while uploading

Tags: python, django, django-models, file-rename, image-upload

Im working on a social media application in django and would like to rename all the images from the uploaded content to make it easier to reuse them (putting them in to a pdf is the end goal, right now the filenames are the same as uploaded and i don't know how put these paths into the pdf --> solution might be numbering them all).

The filename should be renamed to: postimg{num_post}
all posts are numbered. the specific number or the post should be the end of the filename of the image file.

[image: the post feed]

models.py

```
def post_images(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s_%s.%s" % (instance.post.num_post, ext)
    return os.path.join('uploads', filename)

class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    num_post = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images')
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    number_of_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    number_of_dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption
```

views.py

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #user = request.user.username
        image = request.FILES.get('image_upload')
        #--> how to rename the image file to "post{num_post}.jpg"
        caption = request.POST['caption']
        num_post = Post.objects.count()+1
        new_post = Post.objects.create(image=image, caption=caption, num_post=num_post)
        new_post.save()


        #create pdf
        buffer = io.BytesIO()


        #get the image
        #img_file = Image.open(f'{os.getcwd()}/{post.image.url}').convert('RGB')

        #img_file = f'media/post_images/postimg{num_post}'
        #x_start = 0
        #y_start = 0


        #saving it on the server
        folder_path = f"media/post{num_post}.pdf"
        folder_name = os.path.basename(folder_path)


        p = canvas.Canvas(folder_name)

        #p.drawImage(img_file, x_start, y_start, width=120, preserveAspectRatio=True, mask='auto')
        p.drawString(200, 300, new_post.caption)
        p.drawString(200, 100, str(new_post.created_at))
        p.drawString(200, 600, str(new_post.id))

        #p.drawText(new_post.caption)
        #p.drawImage(new_post.image)
        p.showPage()
        p.save()
        buffer.seek(0)
        return redirect('/'), folder_path

    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

so in the end i should be able to put the image in the pdf by using:

```
        img_file = f'media/post_images/postimg{num_post}'
        x_start = 0
        y_start = 0
        p.drawImage(img_file, x_start, y_start, width=120, preserveAspectRatio=True, mask='auto')
```

I was already able to get the images into the pdf by using the existing filename but since the pdf should be automatically generated for each post, the image name needs to be variable, i think.

Right now, it is not working. The image is not renamed, but there is also no error display. so the function seems not to reach the image? How do I make it work?

Thank you for any suggestions. :) im new to django... any explanation helps.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with the model field:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images')
    ...
```

It is not showing any errors because you are uploading files to `'post_images'` folder and not calling a function with such name. And that is also why your files are not being renamed.

To call the rename function, just remove the single quote:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=post_image)
```

Although, it is not going to work because of this line:

```
def post_images(instance, filename):
    ...
    filename = "%s_%s.%s" % (instance.post.num_post, ext)
    ...
```

Where there are two problems. First, `instance` is a `post` object instance, you are trying to access it in the wrong way. And second when trying to format three strings with two parameters. That being said:

```
def post_images(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = 'post{}.{}'.format(instance.num_post, ext)
    return os.path.join('uploads', filename)
```

Lets also implement a [@property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/) on model `Post` so we can access its image filename with ease:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.image.name).split('.')[0]
```

Now, related to the view, it is always a good practice to work with [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#working-with-forms) ([model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)), it also helps writing less code while doing more (like validating data):

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['image', 'caption']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UploadForm
from .models import Post
import os

from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.cleaned_data['num_post'] = Post.objects.count() + 1
            post = Post.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)

            p = canvas.Canvas(os.getcwd() + f'/uploads/converted/{post.filename}.pdf')
            p.drawString(200, 300, post.caption)
            p.drawString(200, 100, str(post.created_at))
            p.drawString(200, 600, str(post.id))
            p.showPage()

            p.drawImage(post.image.name, 0,0, width=A4[0], height=A4[1],mask='auto')
            p.showPage()

            p.save()
            return redirect('post:upload')

    else:
        form = UploadForm()

    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

In this [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#the-view), after checking that the data is valid we then update the valid data dictionary and create the object. Furthermore, since we are using [.create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create) it is not necessary to save the object afterwards.

After this first process we create [ReportLab PDF object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/outputting-pdf/#write-your-view), with two pages, the first one containing the string related data (as in your original function). And, the second one where we [draw an image](https://docs.reportlab.com/reportlab/userguide/ch2_graphics/#image-methods) fitting the whole page by using `from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4` size properties. You can find all this information at the [userguide documentation](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf).

upload.html

```
{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'post:upload' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'post'

urlpatterns = [
    path('upload/', views.upload, name='upload'),
]
```

Comment: hi Niko. This is super helpful. I did not post the whole project code in the answer, because I just needed to solve the naming thing. The pdf would be generated automatically and stored on the server (without the client knowing about it). I already did this with ReportLab but couldn't fit the image inside because of the filename being specific

Comment: Now Ive added your solutions for renaming the image in the uploads folder and it ´s working perfectly. the pdf is created in the upload function at the moment. I will edit the full thing in the post. Im sorry I didn't do that before.

Comment: I would like to stay with the ReportLab pdf creation, because the storing on the server and the implementation of the other values is already working... is there a way to put in the renamed image in this function?

Comment: Yes, of couse. I will update the answer as soon as I can. For future reference just remember to be more specific about the kind of solution you are looking for. :)

Comment: yes, noted. thank you and looking forward to the update.

Comment: So...a minor addition to your `Post` model. And I have renamed the function and other related code to match yours.

Comment: okay. it does not work. There is no pdf created and also no post anymore... also in the code i´ve posted everything is already existing(all the html! --> but i did not post it here since it is very long and for the picture not important... only the image is not in the pdf.

Comment: is there a way to use this line in the original code to get the image? p.drawImage(post.image.name, 0,0, width=A4[0], height=A4[1],mask='auto')

Comment: You instance name is  `new_post` so...`post.image.name` to `new_post.image.name`.

Comment: hello again. I ran into a problem... because the post is created with the same action/button the pdf is, the pdf is unable to get the image, because it is not there in the moment it is requesting it: OSError at /upload
Cannot open resource "uploads/postimg38.jpg". With p.drawImage in the function, no pdf is created due to this error. how do i separate the post and the pdf creation without having a button for each?

Comment: You should be able to create all in one view process, like in our `upload` view. It is just necessary to create the `Post` object prior to the `.pdf` file, so the image can be saved and later retrieved to be drawn. If you still want separate the processes, then write a function for the `.pdf` file creation and call that function from within the view.